# shell_exec() statement to pdftotext entire directory?

Tags: php, foreach, pdftotext

I'm at a loss as to how I could build a loop to `pdftotext` and entire directory through a `shell_exec()` statement.

Something like :

```
$pdfs = glob("*.pdf");

foreach($pdfs as $pdfs) {
    shell_exec('pdftotext '.$pdfs.' '.$pdfs'.txt');
}
```

But I'm unsure how I can drop the .pdf extension the 2nd time I call `$pdfs` in my `shell_exec()` statement and replace that with `.txt`

Not really sure this loop is correct either....

Comment: Yeah, in `foreach($pdfs as $pdfs)` you're reusing the same variable name. Don't do that. `foreach($pdfs as $pdf)` or something (preferably a more noticeable difference in variable name for the sake of sanity :-).

Comment: My `pdftotext` command not running in `exec()` function. Am i missing anything that used in library?

Comment: @SumitMadan i know that you're PHP can't be in safe mode (which is discontinued in 5.4 on, i hear), so that may be one thing....

Comment: @RCNeil what should i do now to run the command in shell_exec or exec.

Comment: `shell_exec()` i believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
foreach(glob("*.pdf") as $src) {

  // Manually remove file extension because glob() may return a dir path component
  $parts = explode('.', $src);
  $parts[count($parts) - 1] = 'txt';
  $dest = implode('.', $parts);

  // Escape shell arguments, just in case
  shell_exec('pdftotext '.escapeshellarg($src).' '.escapeshellarg($dest));

}
```

Basically, loop the PDF files in the directory and execute the command for each one, using just the name component of the file name <strike>(extracted with [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php))</strike><sup>see edit</sup> for the output file (so `test.pdf` becomes `test.txt`).

Using the result of `glob()` directly in `foreach` easily avoids the variable naming collision you had in the code above.

**EDIT**

I have change the above code to manually remove the file extension when generating the output file name. This is because `glob()` may return a directory component of the path strings, as well as just a file name. Using `pathinfo()` or `basename()` will strip this off, and since we know that a `.` will be present in the file name (the rule passed to `glob()` dictates this) we can safely remove everything after the last one. I have also added `escapeshellarg()` for good measure - it is highly unlikely (if not impossible) that a file name that already exists would fall foul of this, but it is best to be safe.

Comment: well your first method worked perfectly, lol.  thanks either way.  good practice is good practice.

Comment: @RCNeil +1 for the Babe reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
$pdfs = glob("*.pdf");

$fmt='/path/to/pdftotext "%s" "%s.txt"';

foreach($pdfs as $thispdf) {
    shell_exec(sprintf($fmt, $thispdf, basename($thispdf, ".pdf")));
}
```